# In Developer Story, make university graduation dates optional

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I do not care to reveal my date of graduation from university. Please make the date fields optional.

Meanwhile, my developer story does none of us any good, because it looks like I did not go to college.

Comment: I'd argue that once you have a few good years of experience under your belt, whether or not you've gone to higher education factors less and less (unless the job specifically requires that you have; then you can have that talk with them when you need to).

Comment: @Makoto - It severely hampers upward mobility to not have higher education.

Comment: I am not debating whether to get an MSECE degree.  I already have it so I obviously should mention it in Developer Story. However, I do not care to reveal my age.  Thus my request to make the dates optional.

Answer (score -13):

Thanks for the feedback.

We're currently looking into improvements we can make to the ordering of items on Developer Stories (including custom ordering).

However we currently rely on the date to choose the order of a story and therefore require them for all items. If we remove the need to rely on dates in the future, we can look at making them optional.

Comment: Could a choice be added to decide if the dates are shown on the developer story and have it default to not showing?

Comment: As the OP, I like the suggestion from @JoeW, except I would make displaying the dates the default.  Thanks, Joe!