# Why are dates required for an Education entry in the Developer Story?

Tags: discussion, bug, developer-story

Many positions require a particular degree; but *when* the applicant earned the degree is irrelevant.

In an industry rife with age discrimination, a degree earned in a too distance past can reduce the chances of being considered for a position.

Or should I simply leave off a degree that I earned too long ago? : )

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336086/in-developer-story-make-university-graduation-dates-optional

Comment: Ah, rats! And I truly searched for that; because I could not believe I was the first to be troubled by this. Thanks for the link, @JeffreyBosboom

Answer (score -12):

I don't see how making the dates optional would help you against any possible age discrimination. The decades of experience would make your rough age a dead giveaway, don't you think?

But you could just leave it off if you wish, it's not like degrees are important once you have 5+ years of experience.

Comment: Unless the job description requires a degree and that's what HR is looking for in their initial pass. No degree listed, no interview.

Comment: Well, I would probably list only my last 10-15 years of experience, since most of the earlier experience would be with irrelevant technology. :-)

Comment: Also, I agree the degree is unimportant, pragmatically, after 5+ years; but there are many, if not most, companies that *require* a degree for some positions.